# mongodb - why name of collections alway is plural?

Tags: mongoose

I use mongoose and schema in express js to create collection.
I don's unserstand why name of collection alway is plural ?
For example : i want to create "member" collection. After running, in my database, "members" collection is created. I re-checked many time to sure that name of collection which i code "member", not be "members".
Did I miss anything ? 
Thanks advances!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the docs, http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection

Mongoose by default use plurals for collection name.

Use collection option to set the name.

`var memberSchema = new Schema({..}, { collection: 'member' })`;